# Terraform destroy throws errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm able to create and execute my `main.tf` file without any errors

```
terraform workspace select dev
terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars -out=devplan.out
terraform apply "devplan.out"
```

But when I try to destroy, I get a bunch of errors as below.

> > terraform destroy
>
> Error: aws_db_parameter_group.oracle_pg: first character of "name"
>   must be a letter
>
> Error: aws_db_parameter_group.oracle_pg: only lowercase alphanumeric
>   characters and hyphens allowed in "name"
>
> Error: aws_security_group.database-sg: "ingress.0.cidr_blocks.0" must
>   contain a valid CIDR, got error parsing: invalid CIDR address:
>
> Error: aws_security_group.oracle_sg: "ingress.0.cidr_blocks.0" must
>   contain a valid CIDR, got error parsing: invalid CIDR address:
>
> Error: aws_security_group.private-sg: "ingress.0.cidr_blocks.0" must
>   contain a valid CIDR, got error parsing: invalid CIDR address:
>
> Error: aws_vpc.vpcname: "cidr_block" must contain a valid CIDR, got
>   error parsing: invalid CIDR address:
>
> Error: module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this: first character of
>   "identifier" must be a letter
>
> Error: module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this: only alphanumeric
>   characters and hyphens allowed in "final_snapshot_identifier"
>
> Error: module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this: only lowercase
>   alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in "identifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `terraform plan`, you know to add `--var-file` options, then you should feed the same to `terraform destroy`

```
terraform destroy -var-file=dev.tfvars
```

Otherwise, `destroy` doesn't know your environment.